# Restoring an iCloud backup

Tags: icloud

I just did a backup of my iPad to iCloud, today.

The idea was to restore my iPad to a backup I did 2 years ago that was stored on my Mac, get some files from there, and return the iPad to what it was today.

I did that, but now that I am trying to restore the iPad to the backup I did today, iCloud says there is nothing there.

What?

Don't tell me I lost everything?

Is there a way to bring back the backup I did today?

edit:

---

1. I have a 2 years old backup on my Mac.
2. I did a backup to iCloud a few hours ago.
3. I restored my iPad to that old backup. Exported some files I had there to iCloud.
4. I tried to restore my iPad to the backup created today.
5. iCloud says there is no backup there. But there is, I confirmed that before doing #3.

My iPad is a 9.7" pro and is updated to the latest iOS.

Comment: If you open iCloud Storage Settings on a Mac/iPhone/iPad and open the backups tab, verify what appears. It should show the date of the backup and device name.

Comment: You may have to call iCloud support in case they can restore the data.

Comment: This does not provide much detail. Try to include informations  such as what have you tried and in which ways didn't it work? What was the error message exactly? What iPadOS version are you running now and what were you running when you backed up 2 years ago? Did the backup show it contained data on your Mac? How did you restored data? etc.

Comment: added more info. @Ezekiel, are you sure apple can restore that?

Comment: You'll have to call and ask they'll be able to try and see. Sometimes they can. Do it as soon as possible to increase the likelihood. Of course they won't be able to restore if the original backup did not complete or something similar.

Comment: @ezekiel, Thanks!

Comment: @Ezekiel, thanks, you saved my bacon. I called Apple, they did a refresh there and then the backup appeared as an option to restore on the iPad. So, the only solution is to call Apple. Please convert your comment into an answer, so I can accept. This can help other people. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

If you are experiencing iCloud data loss, I strongly recommend to reach out to Apple by phone as soon as possible.

For iCloud backups, they may be able to retrieve or appear the data in your UI. For other data, they can sometimes restore server-side backups as well.

The sooner you communicate with them the more likely it is your data is still present in a server-side backup and can be retrieved.